# Fonts seem larger in IE7 & 8 - but only one one page of a site

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In our current project, we have one particular page where, when viewed in IE7 or IE8, fonts seem .1 or .2 em larger than they should be.  Having inspected the code and css, I cannot see where this is coming from.  This issue affects ONLY ONE PAGE which is to all intents and purposes exactly the same as many others in the site, which display as expected.

Some things I have ruled out:

- Text-size settings (it's not that, set to medium, and anyway if so why one page only)
- DPI settings (same reason as above)
- Browser zooming (it's set to 100% - the problem scales with the zoom setting, btw)
- Browser-specific CSS (no browser specific rules are applied to the elements in question)
- Stray font-size setting code in the markup (I've been through and eliminated this)
- Voodoo (okay I haven't ruled this out - as my frustration increases I'm starting to think it might be this though)

The page displays as expected in Firefox.  This is not a live site yet so unfortunately I can't point you at the URL.

Has anyone come across something similar and, if so, what was it?

Many thanks,

G

Comment: Can you take the full page source, put in http://jsfiddle.net/ save then post link here?

Comment: I was not aware of jsfiddle. What a brilliant service. Will do.

Comment: It's been solved now but I'll definitely use that next time. Ta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without showing us or replicating it at least, asking is pretty much near useless but I suspect it's probably just a tag that wasn't closed on an element with an above average font size.

I'd recommend validating the HTML. If it's good, then it's hard to say without looking at the code/page.

Comment: You nailed it - an unclosed span.  Caused by the code behind, which is why I didn't see it in the markup.  My HTML validator had been telling me all this time...